# Using Bing Map in windows 8 store app for all country

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I want to use Bing Map control in my windows 8 application, currently trying with windows 8.1.

I installed Bing map sdk , and referenced to my project as per this 
 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846489.aspx) , and I can use it now.

Here what my problem is I want to use this map for INDIA region, but that is not supported in bing map.
refer this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx)

Can anybody give me a solution to use bing map in India region.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can use the default region and then add you custom TileLayer with your own tile or using the Bing Maps India tiles based on the following url scheme:

```
http://ak.dynamic.t{subdomain}.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=en-in&ur=IN&it=G,VE,BX,L,LA&shading=hill&og=67&n=z
```

A sample code would be:

```
MapTileLayer tileLayer = new MapTileLayer();
tileLayer.TileSource = "http://ak.dynamic.t{subdomain}.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=en-in&ur=IN&it=G,VE,BX,L,LA&shading=hill&og=67&n=z";
map.TileLayers.Add(tileLayer);
map.SetView(new Location(48.03, -122.42), 11, MapAnimationDuration.None);
```

Be careful though, it might be something authorized by the Terms of Use. I would definitely check if it is before implementing it inside an application if I were you. Although, I would prefer to use my own tiles (from my own tile server)

Answer (score 0):

Set the CountryRegion property of the map control to US and it will work. You can set the culture of the map to en-IN, however if you computer is already set to this it will automatically pick that up unless you override it.